# Can Constraint Provider and Score Calculator be set and used at same time

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner, optaweb-vehicle-routing

Can ConstraintProvider and ScoreCalculator set and used at same time? Because it's throwing me exceptions...This is the code...

```
ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig scoreDirectorFactoryConfig = new ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig();
        scoreDirectorFactoryConfig.setConstraintProviderClass(VehicleRoutingConstraintProvider.class);
scoreDirectorFactoryConfig.setInitializingScoreTrend("ONLY_DOWN");
scoreDirectorFactoryConfig.setEasyScoreCalculatorClass(VRPScoreCalculator.class);
solverConfig.setScoreDirectorFactoryConfig(scoreDirectorFactoryConfig);
```

This is the starting few lines of exceptions...

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vehicleRoutingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'vehicleRoutingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vehicleRoutingService' defined in file [/home/bvasavi/Projects/vehicleroutingproblemvijay/target/classes/com/fleetenable/vrp/api/service/VehicleRoutingService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fleetenable.vrp.api.service.VehicleRoutingService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scoreDirectorFactory cannot have an easyScoreCalculatorClass and a constraintProviderClass together.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
```

I figured out that the exceptions are because one can't set `setConstraintProviderClass` and `setEasyScoreCalculatorClass` together...
Can anyone please help me out here!!?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how the two could be used together.